# Is there any way to generate a diff between two versions of an IPython notebook?

Tags: diff, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have started using [IPython notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) quite a bit for writing up draft sections for my dissertation.  However, given two versions of a draft *(i.e., notebook)*, I would like to be able to generate some form of diff output to show what has changed.  Does anyone know if this is currently possible, either through IPython notebook itself, or through some extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet. This is a often a requested feature, but there are different "level" of diff you might want.
Do you want only diff of codecell, or also output, what about prompt number ? etc, etc.

Lots of people have chimed in but nobody really took the time to wrote anything, even if notebook are pretty "simple" json file where cell "just" need to be "aligned" then produce a diffed-json notebook.

Answer (score 20):

Notebook diff can be generated with [nbdime](https://nbdime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). After installing nbdime you can run following to see notebook diff in browser:

`> nbdiff-web notebook_1.ipynb notebook_2.ipynb`

If you are using Github for version control you can use [ReviewNB](https://www.reviewnb.com/) for Notebook diff. It lets you login via Github and browse commits/pull-request diff on your repo. You'll see visual diff like below:

[image]

Comment: it is possible to to that directly using ``nbdiff`- see my answer

Answer (score 10):

Try the following steps:

1. Install `nbdime` by typing `pip install nbdime` on a terminal.
2. Integrate with Git by typing `nbdime config-git --enable --global` on a terminal.
3. Type `nbdiff-web path/to/notebook.ipynb` on a terminal.

You can choose to ignore certain types of cells. For example, if you want to ignore output cells, type:  `nbdiff-web --ignore-outputs  path/to/notebook.ipynb`.

More information on the different diff options here:
https://nbdime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html#common-diff-options

Comment: Which versions are being compared? I tried the commands given and got null response, so perhaps the notebook is being compared with itself.

Comment: By "path" do you mean the path of the file, for example on a Unix system, or do you mean the web-address on, for example, Github?

Comment: @DavidEpstein: Re: null response: By default, `nbdiff` will compare the current state of the notebook with the latest git revision (i.e. it displays what has changed since the last commit). In your case, I would guess your file has not changed since the latest git revision (or it is not in a git repository).

You can also specify which git revisions you wish to compare, or if not using git you can specify two different file paths to compare. See `nbdiff --help` for how.

Comment: @DavidEpstein, re: path: This means the path to the file in the filesystem, with respect to the "working directory" (directory you are in when you're issuing the command).

Answer (score 6):

1- VS Code has added to its Aug 2020 version
[see here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49#_contributions-to-extensions)

2- try [nbdime](https://github.com/jupyter/nbdime)

Comment: Don't feel bad because I'm commenting on your post, it's simply the most recent mentioning nbdime. The web-based front-end failed to show the very first pair of notebooks I tried. The backend seems to spit out compare results but of course it is unable to handle image content and you get console spam. nbdime isn't ready for prime time yet.

Answer (score 4):

Another utility from the [git issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3355) that looks to have gotten official traction is [nbdime](https://github.com/jupyter/nbdime).

Answer (score 3):

Since this question was answered, NBdiff, a diffing and merging tool for the IPython Notebook appeared [on GitHub](https://github.com/tarmstrong/nbdiff). Unfortunately, it has yet to be updated for Jupyter / IPython 3 Notebook format.

Answer (score 1):

[Curvenote](https://curvenote.com) provides a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jupyter-versioning-commen/egkbkefajoeehbmjgelpmdnpgnleknka?hl=en) that allows you to put your notebook in version control and then you can diff individual cells `nbdime` style, but also see previous outputs (plots, tables, streams,...) generated by the different versions of your code.

[image: Diff Jupyter Notebook Cells]

Answer (score 0):

the `nbdiff` utility makes this very simple and effective. Simply issue:

```
nbdiff -DOMI HEAD~ HEAD my_notebook.ipynb
```

where the arguments are here

```
nbdiff [base] [remote] [paths ...]
```

and I have chosen here to compare the current `HEAD` to the previous one `HEAD~` (you can also use a specific commit hash or shorthands such as `HEAD~~`)

Note that I have used `nbdiff -DOMI` to just see the current changes in the code. You can use other combinations - and also the web based

```
nbdiff-web HEAD~ HEAD my_notebook.ipynb
```

which will render a clear ouput such as

[image: nbdiff-web output]

Comment: Hope you could give your dissertation on time :-)